# Obtaining Camera Pose via TF

Tags: ros, calibration, pose, ros-melodic, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the calibration board fixed on the work station, and I have its world coordinates, entered them in URDF, all good. I used OpenCV's pose estimation module to find the board's pose (rvecs and tvecs) from the camera frame as well. This also is OK.  However, I want to get the camera pose (from the world frame) and to do that I think I need to use TF. So basically, we can formulate the problem as follows:

*Given:*

**World -> Board (board in world frame)**

**Board -> Camera (board in camera frame)**

*Find:*

**World -> Camera (world in camera frame, and vice versa, camera in the world frame).**

I have the world and board in my URDF, but since I don't have my camera (which is what I am trying to find out anyway), I don't know how I could utilise TF functionalities.

Does anyone have an experience with this setup?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317682/obtaining-camera-pose-via-tf/) by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2019-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You just have to create a `tf listener` between your two frames, there is a [tutorial in the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29) showing you how to do that.

You can also take a look at the code of [tf_echo](https://github.com/davheld/tf/blob/master/src/tf_echo.cpp).

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-03-06**:
This isn't really an answer tbh. Seeing linked ROS tutorial pages is not why I asked the question. If you have a concrete example showing slightly how this unestablished link between the camera and the world could be created, be my guest. Otherwise, anyone can Google these pages and source files.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-03-06**:
Maybe I haven't understand your question but you said that your inputs are a link between `world` and `board` and a link between `board` and `camera`. So your tf tree is `world -> board -> camera` right ? The tf listener will make the calculation between each link...

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-03-06**:
... eventhough they are not directly connected.
If you run :

```
rosrun tf tf_echo world camera
```

You will get the camera pose in relation to world.

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-03-06**:
You understood it well, that's exactly what I am after. Without having a direct connection, I want to get the camera pose with respect to world. In order words world -> camera.

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-03-06**:
That's the answer yes, we can add that to the answer's body.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2019-03-19**:
For completeness, the line you were looking for in the tutorial was `listener.lookupTransform("/camera", "/world", ros::Time(0), transform);`, tf_echo just outputs the result to the command line.